# Problema con array y punteros en C

Tags: array, c, matrices, punteros

Necesito que alguien me de una mano con esto...

Tengo que escribir un programa en C que efectué efectúe las siguientes operaciones:

a) Declarar un arreglo de quince posiciones de tipo float. Cargar sus elementos y
mostrarlo.

b) Declarar un puntero a float.

c) Asignar al puntero la dirección del arreglo.

d) Recorrer con el puntero el arreglo, mostrando la dirección y el contenido de cada
posición.

Mi problema es cumplir la petición "d", quiero hacerlo pasandole los parámetros a una función para que me lo resuelva. Conseguí la parte de mostrar el contenido, pero no la dirección de memoria en la que se ubican las diferentes posiciones del array.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Agrega en la pregunta el código donde está el problema, de lo contrario, ¿como te ayudaremos?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void print_array(float* ptr)
{
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
        printf("direccion=0x%08llX valor=%f\n", (unsigned long long)&ptr[i], ptr[i]);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // a
    float arreglo[15];
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) arreglo[i]=i;  // cargar correlativo i o cualquier otro numero
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) printf("indice[%d]=%f\n", i, arreglo[i]);

    // b
    float* ptr;

    // c
    ptr = &arreglo[0]; // tbn funciona ptr=arreglo;

    // d
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
        printf("direccion=0x%08llX valor=%f\n", (unsigned long long)&ptr[i], ptr[i]);

    // d usando una funcion
    printf("usando funcion:\n");
    print_array(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow! En esta comunidad no solemos responder a preguntas que no tengan [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).